# Saving data to persistent store bug in BlackBerry 6

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to save a path to an image in the persistent store to show the image when a user chooses a specific product from a history list(one image per product, taken by the user). Now the problem I am having is that when I load the app to the phone for the first time and try adding an entry to the persistent store, it throws an error a bit after and the app freezes. However when I come back, and add an image again, it works just fine and the images always load when I choose each specific product.

This is leading me to believe that the culprit is the first store8.commit() that I'm doing, for some reason it throws an exception : No Stack Trace, when debugging. Here is my code:

```
public class Storage extends Application {

private static final long PERSISTENT_KEY8 = 0x2c4c45c139ee9728L;
static PersistentObject store8 = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(PERSISTENT_KEY8);
private static Vector pics;

/**
 * Picture Section ***********************************************************
 */
public static void savePicture(){

    store8.setContents(new Vector());
    store8.commit();

    if(pics == null){
        pics = new Vector();
    }
    synchronized(store8) {

        store8.setContents(pics); 
        store8.commit();
    }

}
public static String getPicture(String productName){

    if(pics.size()==0){
        return "";
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++){
            Pics product = (Pics)pics.elementAt(i);
            if(product.getProductName().equals(productName)){
                return product.getPic();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }   
}
public static void removePicture(String productName){

    if(pics.size()==0){
        return;
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++){
            Pics product = (Pics)pics.elementAt(i);
            if(product.getProductName().equals(productName)){
                pics.removeElementAt(i);
            }
        }
    }   
}   
public static void loadPicture(){

    pics = (Vector)store8.getContents();

    if(pics == null){
        pics = new Vector();
    }
}
public static void setPicture(Pics pro){
    if(pics.size()!=0){
        for(int j = 0; j< pics.size() ; j++){
            Pics product = (Pics)pics.elementAt(j);
            if(pro.getProductName().equals(product.getProductName())){
                pics.removeElementAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    pics.addElement(pro);
}
}
```

So that is the class that contains my methods to save the image. Now for the other class where I am manipulating it:

```
public class ProductImage extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener,      AppLaunchResource {

private ImageButtonField logo;
private ButtonField newImage, chooseExisting;
public static BitmapField takenPicture;
//public static String picPath =""; 
private String currentPicture = "";
private String currentProduct ="";

public ProductImage(String productName){
    super(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
    currentProduct = productName;
    createGUI(); 
}
public void createGUI(){
    deleteAll();
    this.setTitle(new LabelField("Add An Image", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
    if(ToolbarManager.isToolbarSupported())
    {
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar();
        setToolbar(tb.createToolBar());
    }
    else{
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar();
        add(tb.createNavBar());
    }

    try{
        Storage.loadPicture();
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    newImage = new ButtonField("Take Photo", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK){
        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return (int) (net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth());
        }
    };
    chooseExisting= new ButtonField("Change Image", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK){
        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return (int) (net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth());
        }
    };

    newImage.setChangeListener(this);
    chooseExisting.setChangeListener(this);

    EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("camera.png");
    EncodedImage sizeEnc = ImageResizer.sizeImage(enc, Display.getHeight(), Display.getHeight());

    takenPicture = new BitmapField(enc.getBitmap());

    VerticalFieldManager vfMain = new VerticalFieldManager();
    vfMain.add(new SeparatorField());
    vfMain.add(newImage);
    vfMain.add(chooseExisting);
    vfMain.add(takenPicture);
    add(vfMain);

    currentPicture = Storage.getPicture(currentProduct);
    showPicture();

}   

public void choosePicture(){

    String imageExtensions[] = {"jpg", "jpeg",
         "bmp", "png", "gif"};

    FileSelectorPopupScreen fps = new FileSelectorPopupScreen(null, imageExtensions);
    fps.pickFile();
    String theFile = fps.getFile();
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(fps);

    if (theFile == null)
    {
        Dialog.alert("Screen was dismissed. No file was selected.");
    }
    else
    {
        try{

            String path= "file:///" + theFile;
            byte[] data = getData(path);
            //Encode and Resize image 
            EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data,0,data.length);

            if(Display.getHeight()>Display.getWidth()){
                int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), 
                     Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));
                int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
                     Fixed32.toFP((Display.getWidth()*Display.getWidth())/Display.getHeight()));
                eImage=eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            }
            else{
                int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), 
                         Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));
                    int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
                         Fixed32.toFP(Display.getHeight()));
                    eImage=eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            }
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(fps);
            takenPicture.setBitmap(eImage.getBitmap());

            Storage.setPicture(new Pics(currentProduct, path));

            try{
                Storage.savePicture();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }       
        Dialog.alert("Picture Saved");
    }

}
public void showPicture(){
    if(currentPicture != ""){
        try{

            String path= currentPicture;
            byte[] data = getData(path);
            //Encode and Resize image 
            EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data,0,data.length);

            if(Display.getHeight()>Display.getWidth()){
                int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), 
                     Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));
                int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
                     Fixed32.toFP((Display.getWidth()*Display.getWidth())/Display.getHeight()));
                eImage=eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            }
            else{
                int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), 
                         Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));
                    int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
                         Fixed32.toFP(Display.getHeight()));
                    eImage=eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            }





            takenPicture.setBitmap(eImage.getBitmap());

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }  
    }
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

    if(field == logo){

    }
    else if(field == newImage){
        takePicture();
    }
    else if(field == chooseExisting){
        choosePicture();
    }
}

}
```

I removed many parts of this class, sorry if it is long, there are basically 4 Storage method calls in this code and I believe they are all in the right place.. but again im having the problem on first load, not afterwards.

Can anyone see what Im doing wrong here? I have had this problem for a week

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: You do `pics.removeElementAt` without `--i` or `--j` hence you skip the next entry.

Comment: Tried adding these, did not change the output.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Instead of using `--i` or `--j`, the loops should be using `break` instead when a match is found.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes thought that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class Storage extends Application{ 

    private static final long PERSISTENT_KEY8 = 0x2c4c45c139ee9728L; 
    static PersistentObject store8 = null; 
    private static Vector pics = null; 

    static{
        store8 = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(PERSISTENT_KEY8)
        pics = (Vector)store8.getContents(); 
        if(pics == null){ 
            pics = new Vector(); 
            store8.setContents(pics);
            store8.commit();
        } 
    }

    public static void savePicture(){
        try{
            synchronized(store8){ 
                store8.setContents(pics);  
                store8.commit(); 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){       
            e.printStackTrace();       
        }       
    } 

    public static int findPicture(String productName){
        for(int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++){ 
            Pics product = (Pics)pics.elementAt(i); 
            if(product.getProductName().equals(productName)){ 
                return i; 
            } 
        } 
        return -1; 
    } 

    public static String getPicture(String productName){
        int idx = findPicture(productName);
        if(idx != -1){
            return ((Pics)pics.elementAt(idx)).getPic(); 
        } 
        return ""; 
    } 

    public static void removePicture(String productName){
        int idx = findPicture(productName);
        if(idx != -1){
            pics.removeElementAt(idx); 
        }    
    }    

    public static void setPicture(Pics pro){ 
        removePicture(pro.getProductName());
        pics.addElement(pro); 
    } 
}
```

.

```
public class ProductImage extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener, AppLaunchResource {       
    private ImageButtonField logo;       
    private ButtonField newImage, chooseExisting;       
    public static BitmapField takenPicture;       
    //public static String picPath ="";        
    private String currentPicture = "";       
    private String currentProduct = "";       

    public ProductImage(String productName){       
        super(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);       
        currentProduct = productName;       
        createGUI();        
    }       

    public void createGUI(){       
        deleteAll();       
        setTitle(new LabelField("Add An Image", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));       
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar();       
        if(ToolbarManager.isToolbarSupported()){       
            setToolbar(tb.createToolBar());       
        }       
        else{       
            add(tb.createNavBar());       
        }       

        newImage = new ButtonField("Take Photo", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK){       
            public int getPreferredWidth() {       
                return (int) Display.getWidth();       
            }       
        };       

        chooseExisting = new ButtonField("Change Image", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK){       
            public int getPreferredWidth() {       
                return (int) Display.getWidth();       
            }       
        };       

        newImage.setChangeListener(this);       
        chooseExisting.setChangeListener(this);       

        EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("camera.png");       
        EncodedImage sizeEnc = ImageResizer.sizeImage(enc, Display.getHeight(), Display.getHeight());       

        takenPicture = new BitmapField(enc.getBitmap());       

        VerticalFieldManager vfMain = new VerticalFieldManager();       
        vfMain.add(new SeparatorField());       
        vfMain.add(newImage);       
        vfMain.add(chooseExisting);       
        vfMain.add(takenPicture);       
        add(vfMain);       

        currentPicture = Storage.getPicture(currentProduct);       
        showPicture();       
    }          

    public void choosePicture(){       
        String imageExtensions[] = {"jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif"};       

        FileSelectorPopupScreen fps = new FileSelectorPopupScreen(null, imageExtensions);       
        fps.pickFile();       
        String theFile = fps.getFile();       

        if (theFile == null){       
            Dialog.alert("Screen was dismissed. No file was selected.");       
            return;
        }       

        EncodedImage eImage = loadImage("file:///" + theFile);
        if(eImage != null){
            takenPicture.setBitmap(eImage.getBitmap());       
            Storage.setPicture(new Pics(currentProduct, path));       
            Storage.savePicture();       
            Dialog.alert("Picture Saved");       
        }       
    }       

    private EncodedImage loadImage(String path){
        try{       
            byte[] data = getData(path);       
            //Encode and Resize image        
            EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data,0,data.length);       

            int scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY;

            if(Display.getHeight()>Display.getWidth()){       
                scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));       
                scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), Fixed32.toFP((Display.getWidth()*Display.getWidth())/Display.getHeight()));       
            }       
            else{       
                scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth()));       
                scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), Fixed32.toFP(Display.getHeight()));       
            }       

            return eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void showPicture(){       
        if(currentPicture != ""){       
            EncodedImage eImage = loadImage(currentPicture);
            if (eImage != null){
                takenPicture.setBitmap(eImage.getBitmap());       
           }
        }       
    }       

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){       
        if(field == logo){       
        }       
        else if(field == newImage){       
            takePicture();       
        }       
        else if(field == chooseExisting){       
            choosePicture();       
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your app inside a debugger so you can see exactly what is crashing?

Comment: It crashes on the commit() in Storage.savePicture();  
When I print the exception it says : No Stack Trace. But again, only on first load

Comment: What type of exception is `commit()` throwing?  It is documented as throwing either a `NonPersistableObjectException` or a `PersistentContentException`. I'm guessing the former, because `Vector` does not implement the `Persistable` interface, which `commit()` requires.  You can store only persistable objects in the `PersistentStore`.

Comment: I am getting this message: net.rim.device.api.system.NonPersistableObjectException

However why does it work after the first crash? seems like it is only throwing this on the first load

Comment: Okay I was saving a class I made myself inside the Vector, but did not implement Persistable interface in these classes. I will try it this way.

Comment: It worked! the classes just needed to implement Persistable. Thanks for your help, the answer was in your last comment